# Unable to get the iterative logic for my recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, iteration

I have a map as follows:

```
A=[B]
B=[C,D,E]
C=[F,G,H,I]
```

What I need exactly is that each parent should have its respective children and the children if they have any children should be listed within them as shown below

```
tree = [
      {
        label: 'A',
        children: [
          {
            label: 'B',
            children: [
{
             label:'C',
children: ['F','G','H','I']
}, 'D','E']
          }
        ]
}]
```

I wrote a recursive logic to do it and it works fine till the tree size is within 200. But once it crosses 200 I am getting stackoverflowerror. I found in some links of SO related to error, that iterative logic can be used instead of recursive logic. So I started to do it. But I am not sure how to convert it. I am totally stuck with it. Below is my code:

```
private JsonArray getChildren(String parent)

    {

        JsonArray thisLevelParent = new JsonArray();
        JsonArray children = new JsonArray();

        if (topicsMap.containsKey(parent)) {

            ArrayList<String> childList = new ArrayList<String>();
            childList = topicsMap.get(parent);

            for (int i = 0; i < childList.size(); i++) {
                String par = childList.get(i);
                if (topicsMap.containsKey(par)) {
                    children = getChildren(par);

                } else {
                    System.out.println();
                    children = new JsonArray();

                }
                JsonObject dataObj = new JsonObject();
                dataObj.add("label", new JsonParser().parse(par));
                dataObj.add("children", children);

                thisLevelParent.add(dataObj);

            }

        }

        return thisLevelParent;
    }
```

Any help/suggestion would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to do a DFS with a stack.

Comment: just fyi dfs === depth first search: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Comment: Hi @HadiAmiri Ya I did DFS and I was successful in converting the recursive method to iterative method. Couldn't believe I forgot that DFS existed :( Thanks for reminding and Can you please write an answer so that I can mark it as answer